# Excel formula to show prices based on 3 different dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

What is the excel formula to do below:

```
1. lookup from three or more different rows of dates (Q,R,S)
2. lookup the corresponding prices from another table based on these dates
3. fill the correct price based on the dates of another table
```

Below is a snapshot of what i would like the final outcome

SAMPLE DATA
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  if you were to [edit] your question to include some sample data, and more of an explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, it would help clarify what you're trying to accomplish.  Also, take a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula will work for your sample data.  You will need to adjust the ranges to suit your needs.  There are other formulas that will produce the same results.  The formula was initially set up assuming that the index numbers and dates were unique in their reference tables.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B4,$B$14:$E$19,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($Q$4:$S$8)/(C$3=$Q$4:$S$8),1)-COLUMN($Q$3)+2,0),"Date or Index not found")
```

The iferror portion displays an error message for you should the date or index value (1201...1206, etc) not be found in either table.

[image]

Comment: but i have a little problem, the prices seem to jump if there are more than 3 date rows to choose from.  I my case i have 7 rows of dates and can i make it so that if no date was found will go to a range of prices?

Comment: i have enclosed the final sample data, the prices for Price +3 and Price +2 seems to be displaying fine but after the prices that it displays jumps. can please tell me what i am doing wrong.  thanks again

Comment: From the sounds of what you are describing, you probably did not adjust one of the address ranges to cover all the expanded areas.  Based on your second comment, I am guessing you said row when you meant column.  important thing to remember is that the number of date columns from step 1 and step 2 have to be equal.

Comment: Yes you can make it so if the date is not found it will look in a specific column in step 2.  place the whole aggregate part inside an IFERROR, and make the part when an error occurs equal to the column number from step 2.